# Unable to return encode :date types in Poison

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using the default json tools in Phoenix, but for some reason I can't return any dates (field type :date).  I get something like this:

```
unable to encode value: {2015, 3, 24}
```

I'm using a postgres db with the field in the db of type date.  Am I missing something? Do I need to build a function to parse the date before I encode it with poison?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind--"{" and "}" are reserved characters in JSON. I'd guess you need to either escape them or figure out some means of just getting the year, month and date from the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your "date object" is just an Elixir tuple. Posion does not know how to encode Elixir tuples:

```
iex(1)> Poison.encode({2015, 3, 24}) 
{:error, {:invalid, {2015, 3, 24}}}
```

If you format your date into a string first, Posion will have no trouble encoding it into JSON:

```
iex(2)> Poison.encode(:io_lib.format("~4..0B-~2..0B-~2..0B", [2015, 3, 24]) |> List.flatten |> to_string)
{:ok, "\"2015-03-24\""}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd probably structure that a little different: :io_lib.format("~4..0B-~2..0B-~2..0B", [2015, 3, 24]) |> List.flatten |> to_string |> Poison.encode

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're not using string interpolation instead of `:io_lib.format/2`?

Comment: @whatyouhide No good reason, no. Either will work, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to get better in the next Phoenix release (v0.11):

1. The new Phoenix version will automatically include encoders for `Ecto.DateTime` and `Ecto.Date` via the [phoenix_ecto](http://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_ecto) project. So it should just work™.
2. That said, you likely want to use `Ecto.DateTime`, `Ecto.Date` and friends instead of `:datetime` and `:time` as you will work with structs and not tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jordan Dimov above, I ended up making a module called formatter, which has a variant of this formatting and a money formatter.  Here it is, in case it is helpful to anyone:

```
defmodule Myapp.Formatter do



def date(date) do
    :io_lib.format("~4..0B-~2..0B-~2..0B", Tuple.to_list(date))
      |> List.flatten
      |> to_string
  end

  def money(money) do
    (money.coef/100)*money.sign
  end

end
```

I aliased the module under :view in the myapp.Web module, so the functions are available in my views to format before returning the Json.  Thanks!